# AWS Elastic bean stalk : Error matching signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I created AWS account, deployed [amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample](http://find-deve-1ehukalzjzwxr-dixjsh8sm8.elasticbeanstalk.com/) using Amazon CloudFormation.

I was able to register new users by URL :  url/jsp/register.jsp provided by Cloud formation output.

Then I downloaded  [CognitoSyncDemo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) and followed all the instructions.

Following are initials as instructed in sample

Username : registered user (@ cloud_formation_output_url/jsp/register.jsp)
appname  : awscognitodeveloperauthenticationsample 
endpoint : http://find-deve-1#########-*********.elasticbeanstalk.com/  
developerProvider : login.findit

but I am getting 
response code : 401
response body : Error matching signature

Signature is made up of Username + appname + endpoint

I guess the issue is with appname as I have crosschecked endpoint twice.

Can some one please guide me what appname to use as there are three services, each having a name
 
1. Cognito  have : identity pool name
2. Cloud formation have  : stack name
3. Elastic BeanStalk : app name

I am confused with app name. Right now I am using default app name provided in sample itself. Not sure what name to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours found that endpoint to mention is not the endpoint from elastic beanstalk as mentioned in sample for android, but I have to mention Application URL which is there under outputs tab in cloud formation console when stack created by me is selected.